# Twilio Requirements to invoke AddOns have not been met

Tags: curl, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using Twilio to get information about my number. I installed the "Ekata Reverse Phone" Addon. Now, whenever I try to do a Curl request from my Linux machine or use the URL "https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+XXXXXXXXXX/?AddOns=ekata_reverse_phone" to get information. I get this error

> "message": "Requirements to invoke AddOns have not been met"

The complete response (X represents the digits of my phone number):

```
{"caller_name": null, "country_code": "IN", "phone_number": "+XXXXXXXXXX", "national_format": "XXXXXX XXXXX", "carrier": null, "add_ons": {"status": "successful", "message": null, "code": null, "results": {"ekata_reverse_phone": {"status": "failed", "request_sid": "my credential", "message": "Requirements to invoke AddOns have not been met", "code": 61003, "result": {}}}}, "url": "https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+XXXXXXXXXX"}
```

Things I tried:

Going to the Catalog (Ekata Reverse Phone addon page)
Make sure Ekata Reverse Phone is installed
Make sure the Lookup checkbox is marked under the configuration tab

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me when I tested it out:
`https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+1XXXXXXXXXX/?AddOns=ekata_reverse_phone`

Did you enable "Use In" for Lookup?

[image: Ekata Reverse Phone AddOn Configuration]

Comment: Yes, I enabled Lookups. It works with US numbers but when I try Indian number or any other country it gives that error.

Comment: If you're having issues with this addOn, you can request support from Ekata. In your Twilio console, find the addOn and then visit the _Support_ tab and you will see how to contact them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll contact them.

Comment: I just ran into this too, I think it's only working for US numbers.